# Custom logical "and" operator

Tags: c#, operators

I have built my own query builder and parser for some use.
it is working fine today.
I want to change the api so instead of writing `.And()` and `.Or()`, I want to write `&&` `||` , like in IQueryable.
Is it possible in my situation?:

```
interface IQ{
     IQ And(IQ q);
     IQ Or(IQ q);
}

class StringQ : IQ{

}
class IntQ : IQ{

}
// this is how I write the query today:
IQ q = new StringQ("a == str").Or(new IntQ("b == 1"));

// I want to write the query - not the || statement
IQ q = new StringQ("a == str") || new IntQ("b == 1")
```

So the `||` statement will host `IQ` in it.
something like:

```
interface IQ{
     IQ &&(IQ q);
     IQ ||(IQ q);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can show us an example of how it would look like using `IQueryable`?

Comment: Operators are implemented as a static method, so I don't think it's possible to make it part of the interface. That leaves us either implementing it in the concrete class, or making custom methods in the interface (such as And).

Comment: Have you not found my answer helpful?

Comment: @OndrejJanacek - not, since it is static operation....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it could be done with some effort.

First, you know that these operators can be overloaded [in a way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx).

> The conditional logical operators cannot be overloaded, but they are evaluated using & and |, which can be overloaded.

Second, you need a little trick to be able to force implementation of overloaded operators - for this, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811278/is-there-any-way-in-c-sharp-to-enforce-operator-overloading-in-derived-classes) SO question.

If you want to know my opinion this effort is not worth the benefits you see in it.