# Anyway to check that the new member of class is used by the operator in C#?

Tags: c#

Let's say I created a class name "CharacterStat" that has members like health, attack, moveSpeed... and I override the operator  "+, -" for the class. Later I add more members such as armor and dexterity. Is there any way to check that I don't forget to implement them in +,- operator?

Comment: Write unit tests or check with eyes.

Comment: Refer it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811278/is-there-any-way-in-c-sharp-to-enforce-operator-overloading-in-derived-classes

Comment: The short answer is no, you can't enforce this.

Comment: Closed first as duplicate of [enforce + in derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811278/is-there-any-way-in-c-sharp-to-enforce-operator-overloading-in-derived-classes) but it looks like you are actually trying to glimpse inside `operator +` for single class (and there is no inheritance)...

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about missing out on adding new stats to `operator+` and all of the stats are of the same type, *generate* the code rather than writing it. If you put this in a `.tt` file (and make sure that the "Custom Tool" property for it is set to `TextTemplatingFileGenerator`:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
namespace Abc
{
    public class CharacterStat{
        <# GenerateBasicStats("attack","health","moveSpeed"); #>
    }
}
<#+
    public void GenerateBasicStats(params string[] statNames)
    {
        //Readonly props
        foreach(var name in statNames){
            WriteLine("public int {0} {{get;}} ",name);
        }

        //Constructor
        Write("public CharacterStat(");
        bool first = true;
        foreach(var name in statNames){
            if(!first) Write(", ");
            first = false;
            Write("int {0}",name);
        }
        WriteLine(")");
        WriteLine("{");
        foreach(var name in statNames){
            WriteLine("this.{0} = {0};",name);
        }
        WriteLine("}");

        //Operator+
        WriteLine("public static CharacterStat operator+(CharacterStat left, CharacterStat right)");
        WriteLine("{");
        Write("return new CharacterStat(");
        first = true;
        foreach(var name in statNames)
        {
            if(!first) Write(", ");
            first = false;
            Write("left.{0} + right.{0}",name);
        }
        WriteLine(");");
        WriteLine("}");
    }
#>
```

We produce this class:

```
namespace Abc
{
  public class CharacterStat
  {
    public int attack { get; }
    public int health { get; }
    public int moveSpeed { get; }
    public CharacterStat(int attack, int health, int moveSpeed)
    {
      this.attack = attack;
      this.health = health;
      this.moveSpeed = moveSpeed;
    }
    public static CharacterStat operator +(CharacterStat left, CharacterStat right)
    {
      return new CharacterStat(left.attack + right.attack, left.health + right.health, left.moveSpeed + right.moveSpeed);
    }
  }
}
```

(Okay, not as pretty as that but it can be cleaned up). Now you won't forget because adding a new stat is done in *one* place and it makes sure it has a property, is included in the constructor *and* is covered by `operator+`.

More reading - [Code Generation and T4 Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no built in support to check if "all fields of a class are used in a given method".

Your options:

- carefully review code and have good unit test coverage
- rewrite your `operator +` to use reflection and explicitly collect information on all fields that need to be added/subtracted.
- use some IL parser to dig into compiled implementation of the code for `operator+` and hope it is written in a relatively repeated way so you can make sense of IL.